# RSS/Atom schema that validates all the different spec versions of the feeds

Tags: xml, rss, schema, specifications, atom-feed

I'm trying to build an open source tool that will accept RSS/Atom URL feeds as input data and then, I want to validate these entries to avoid errors when parsing the XML results. I've searched for schema files that meet my needs, but I found too many schema definitions for an unlimited version of these specs. So, I want to know if anybody has a unified schema or a collection of them that I can use to validate these feeds against?

Comment: There is already an open source tool that does that, perhaps you would be better off contributing to that project instead of reinventing the wheel? http://sourceforge.net/projects/feedvalidator/

Comment: @David, the tool i'm building is not about atom/rss validation. Validation is only a way to evict bad data and bugs when the real deal happens. But, thanks anyway, this project will help me a lot. :-P

Comment: Oh, in that case, I'll make it an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Feed Validator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/feedvalidator/) project is open source and has [an API](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/soap.html) that you can use from your program. For performance and so you don't overload the W3C service (which, IIRC, depends on donations) I recommend installing a local copy of the Feed Validator.